# gcc installation on Mac El Capitan

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I'm trying to compyling wgrib (it needs c and fortran compiler) on my Mac osx 10.11.6 (El Capitan) but the gcc compiler seems not work. I installed Xcode 7.3 and the command line developer tools from the Apple's developer page. But if I type on the Terminal windows this:

```
gcc --version--
```

the answer is:

> `clang: error: unsupported option '--version--'.`

Comment: `gcc --version--` --->  `gcc --version`

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is **gcc --version** instead of **gcc --version--**

Comment: This is a comment, not a n answer

Comment: @LPs actually it can be reworded into an answer.

Comment: In fact I've now done that. Ander, you can still undo my edit if you disagree with it.

Comment: Thats why I posted like an answer

Comment: @immibis Yes, but I prefer to see owner efforts ;)

Comment: @LPs When it gives you the solution within the question itself ;)